# Woocommerce - Display prices next to variation - formatting

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following code I found to display the prices next to the variations in WooCommerce.

It works brilliantly, **but the prices are not aligned**, when the length of the variations differ. (image attached).

How to align these texts (prices)? This is the [site](https://flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com/product/burst-of-sunshine/).

**Code:**

```
//Add prices to variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );

function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
   global $wpdb, $product;

   $result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'");

   $term_slug = ( !empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;

   $query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
   FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
   LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
   WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
   AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
   AND products.post_parent = $product->id";

   $variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

   $parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );

   if ( $parent > 0 ) {
      $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );

      //this is where you can actually customize how the price is displayed
      return $term . '  ' . woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ) . '';
   }
   return $term;
}
```

Comment: What CSS have you tried? Please supply a link where we can see this issue.

Comment: I have not tried any CSS.. We've had the site designed by someone and i'm just learning my way around.. so i'm not sure what I would add to the CSS.. or where to put it...

Comment: You can view the issue here- As you can see, the prices are not aligned https://flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com/product/burst-of-sunshine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this CSS.

```
.tm-extra-product-options .tmcp-field-wrap .amount {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 12px;
}
```

Ideally, CSS like this should be within a [WordPress child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). However, if you are just working out your way around, this plugin may also help you: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Thanks

Comment: Oh this is brilliant.. thank you!! ! I just added it to the bottom of the custom.css page and it works perfectly! One question though, I want to get it a little closer to the middle, as it is now at the very far right... how come if I change the text "right: 0;" to something else e.g "right: 20;" nothing happens?

Comment: It requires a **px** added after the number. Ex, **20px** or a minus value to move left, **-30px**

Comment: If this has helped you, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect.. you're a genius!! Thank you!! :)

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Comment: I noticed last night, because we made the position absolute (i'm guessing), it doesn't show up when loaded on an ipad. Is there a way to make this responsive? Thanks!!!

Comment: I'd need to see the issue back on your site with the CSS. You can use Media Queries to override the provided CSS. Ref: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPad

Comment: How do I write the media query so that it knows i'm referring to this item specifically (the alignment of the prices).. I see there are some media query codes in my css file, but they seem to be very global. how would you write a media query referring to just this? (I hope this makes sense)

Comment: You can out your code within a media query. Ex: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/